# Java program keeps writing to disk when laptop is running on battery

Tags: java, battery

I notice that when my laptop is running on battery, java applications (e.g. JabRef)
will write to HDD every 5 seconds or so, as shown by iotop:

```
11:05:42 23199 be/4 yopology    0.00 B/s    7.39 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -jar /opt/bin/JabRef-2.10.jar
11:05:48 23199 be/4 yopology    0.00 B/s    7.38 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -jar /opt/bin/JabRef-2.10.jar
11:05:52 23199 be/4 yopology    0.00 B/s    7.38 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -jar /opt/bin/JabRef-2.10.jar
11:05:57 23199 be/4 yopology    0.00 B/s    7.42 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -jar /opt/bin/JabRef-2.10.jar
11:06:03 23199 be/4 yopology    0.00 B/s    7.40 K/s  0.00 %  0.00 % java -jar /opt/bin/JabRef-2.10.jar
```

But the frequency reduces to about once every 30 seconds when the laptop is running on AC adaptor. I wonder what causes that and how may I fix it.

Comment: Is it monitoring battery life?

Comment: I am not sure. It will be good if I can know which file it is writing to, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

> JabRef is a reference management software that uses BibTeX as its native format. JabRef provides an easy-to-use interface for editing BibTeX files, for importing data from online scientific databases, and for managing and searching BibTeX files.

I have no idea why it is writing to file. However, this comamnd:

```
find . -type d -name .svn -prune -o -cmin -0.083 -type f -print
```

will find all files modified in the last 5 seconds. Try running that to see what's changing?

(Browser cache files show up there, so make sure you don't use any other applications just before you run it).

Comment: I tried this command as you suggested. It found the file ~/.java/.userPrefs/.userRootModFile.yopology; however, the file size is zero and the timestamp does not seem to have changed. Now I am puzzled... BTW, the frequent disk writing is not specifically for JabRef. I found similar behaviour from other Java programs too.

Comment: Hmm that is very strange...